# insert row with max(id)+1 of table

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I has `events` table without primary key but id column is unique(i can not change table structure).

```
id|name
_______
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
```

I want run this query for insert new row

```
insert into event (id, name) values ((select max(id) + 1 from event), 'd')
```

I write this code

```
var evn_event= _unitOfWork.EventRepository.GetQueryableAsync();
long EVENT_CNT = evn_event.Max(x => x.EVENT_CNT)+1;

var entity = new EVENT
{
    id = EVENT_CNT,
    name = 'd',            
};
var result =  _unitOfWork.EventRepository.InsertAsync(entity, autoSave: true);
```

With this code some time i get exception for id value entered is not unique(Because a record has been inserted in the interval between select max id and insert).

**Question**:how can write equal code of this query

```
insert into event (id, name) values ((select max(id) + 1 from event), 'd')
```

that `select max(id)+1` run sync with insert statement?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use `identity` column for this that will handle uniqueness and locks in transactional way.

Comment: @astentx i can not change table structure

Comment: Which EF Core version? With EF Core 7 you [can use stored procedure for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#stored-procedure-mapping)

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided?  Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better option to remove the above process, You have to change the table structure so that you don't have to fill Id manually.
execute it to the SQL server.

```
Alter table event Add id_emp INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Then You can modify your insert record logic as

```
var entities = new Event{
name="d"
}
var result =  _unitOfWork.EventRepository.InsertAsync(entities , autoSave: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> With this code some time i get exception for id value entered is not
> unique(Because a record has been inserted in the interval between
> select max id and insert).

Actually, you are getting the right exception as you it missing the sequence. In that scenario, for first insertion you will always get the exception because while using [Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-8.0) it requires sequence but at the begining there wouldn't be any value and in order to overcome this, you would need to descencing your list and have to check if that return null. As first time it will null which can be handled using [ternary operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Let's have a look in action:

Assuming I have following model:

```
public class EVENT
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }  
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(EVENT eventModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Getting Last Inserted Id
                int lastSequence = _context.EVENTs.OrderByDescending(id => id.id).FirstOrDefault() == null ? 0 : _context.EVENTs.OrderByDescending(id => id.id).FirstOrDefault().id;

                //Creating new Id
                var newId = lastSequence + 1;
                //Binding Object
                var _objEvent = new EVENT();
                _objEvent.id = newId;
                _objEvent.name = eventModel.name;
             

                _context.EVENTs.Add(_objEvent);
                _context.SaveChanges();


            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Note:** I am using `null ? 0` ternary to handle null in case of first insertion as it will be null at the begining.

Output:

[image]